# Rails I18n not cascading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cascade, rails-i18n

I would like to use the I18n cascading module as described [here](http://svenfuchs.com/2011/2/11/organizing-translations-with-i18n-cascade-and-i18n-missingtranslations), but I cannot get the cascading to working.

I've a YAML file as follows:

```
follows:
  every_x_day: "value here"
  ...
  main:
    ...
```

In follows/main view, I'm calling the t helper for the key '.every_x_day', which is just short for 'follows.main.every_x_day'. No such key is of course found, so I would expect the cascading to look next for 'follows.every_x_day', but this does not happen.

I've seen the question and the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510500/rails-i18n-cascading-how-to-get-it-to-work): I've added the

```
I18n.backend.class.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Cascade)
```

to application.rb. But when I call the translation helper with cascade: true, it simply does not cascade. The page just shows that the translation is missing (key name on magenta background).

I've also checked it with this [i18n patch](http://web.archive.org/web/20120619002316/http://www.unixgods.org/~tilo/Rails/where_is_Rails_trying_to_lookup_L10N_strings.html). It also shows that no cascading search happens. It just looks for the most specific key, doesn't find anything, and stops searching.

Any ideas what is causing this behaviour?

Comment: Please show me exactly how you pass the cascading option, including the exact formatting for the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was caused by the I18n-monkeypatch (see the original question). After disabling the monkeypatch, the cascading took place as it should. This was carelessness on my part, apparently I never tested the app without the monkeypatch.

Anyway, thanks for taking the time to help klaffenboeck.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I assume that you have something like this in your code:

```
<%= t('.every_x_day', cascade: true) %>
```

Are you completely sure, that `'.every_x_day'` starts looking for the key in `'follows.main.every_x_day'` The way I describe it in the answer in my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510500/rails-i18n-cascading-how-to-get-it-to-work) is the normal behaviour for the I18n and the lazy-lookup in views. So, the first thing I would try is to pass the full key into the helper:

```
<%= t('follows.main.every_x_day', cascade: true) %>
```

Then you can at least be sure, that your original lookup-path is correct. 
If that doesn't work, then the cascading module isn't loaded. 
Did you put the code inside the config-options? (see my [updated_answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18510500/rails-i18n-cascading-how-to-get-it-to-work)).

If it still doesn't work, come back at me and we will try to figure it out together.